# How to view bdmv or m2ts file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I have a movie which has a bunch of *.m2ts file. How can I watch it in ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried VLC? I believe it *should* play such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) for Ubuntu [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many viewers for that file type.

m2ts is *MPEG2 Transport Stream* - basically the same stream format as digital TV.

The simplest player is *mplayer* but AFAIK most players will play it happily.